# How is the earth soon after God turn the light on according to the literalist / YEC?

Tags: genesis, creation, young-earth-creation, literalism

> Genesis 1:2
>  Then God said, "Let there be light"; and there was light.

Is the other half of earth dark?

My understanding is that when the light was created, then (logically) the other half of the earth is dark.  What are the conditions of light and darkness on the Earth when the Light came into being?  The answers need to be from the YEC beliefs and perspective.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast, "turn the light on" I mean "create the light" as it read in Genesis 1:2. It's difficult for me to imagine, as generally based from what I know that a light has a one point source - and when there is a solid object in front of the light, the other part of the object don't receive the light (dark). That's why (if I'm a literalist) I can not figure out how is the condition of "separating the light from darkness".

Comment: From the verse, what I get of the condition is : (1) totally dark (2) God create the light (3) YET, the darkness still there. (4) God separate it. So, if I choose that once God created the light resulting the whole universe is bright because of the light without exception (including the other part of the earth and every where of other solid object if any) - but then how is the darkness still there up until God separate it ?

Comment: "How is the earth soon" I mean is : how is the earth, soon after God created the light and darkness, Korvin. Before God separate the light, before there is morning there is evening - before Day 1, 24 hours past.

Comment: Yes. That's what I mean. Because, I thought that when the light created - then (logically) the other half of the earth is dark. But that's only in my own thinking.  "what are the conditions of light and darkness on the Earth" this one what I mean.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast, yes Korvin. Thank you for the editing. And I'm sorry as I can not elaborate my question correctly. And I'm the one who should say thanks :).

Comment: Thanks for working with me on that, I was having a hard time understanding the question.

Comment: The sun and moon and stars are on day four. Our usual understanding of earth rotations, one side light and the other dark, would, I believe, come into play then.

Comment: @AdrianKeister, one side light and the other dark, would, I believe, come into play then ---> you mean come into play on day four ?

Comment: @karma, Exactly.

Comment: @AdrianKeister, would you please put your comment as an answer, Adrian ? And would you please describe how is the earth's condition soon after God created light and then on day one to day three according YEC if  the condition one side light and the other half of the earth is dark happen on day four ? Thank you, Adrian.

Answer (score 1):

At this point light and darkness existed at the same time. It is unclear if they were intermingled or not.

> Genesis 1:4 KJV And God saw the light, that it was good: and God divided the light from the darkness.

In the above scripture God moved light and Darkness apart, but we do not know if they were something like twilight or if they were so to speak side by side.

As far as one side of the Earth being in light and the opposite side in darkness that is a function of sunlight, which did not exist until:

> Genesis 1:14 through 19 KJV And God said, Let there be lights in the firmament of the heaven to divide the day from the night; and let them be for signs, and for seasons, and for days, and years: And let them be for lights in the firmament of the heaven to give light upon the earth: and it was so. And God made two great lights; the greater light to rule the day, and the lesser light to rule the night: he made the stars also. And God set them in the firmament of the heaven to give light upon the earth, And to rule over the day and over the night, and to divide the light from the darkness: and God saw that it was good.  And the evening and the morning were the fourth day.

In the above Scriptures we learn that this was the beginning of time. Time is the passage of cycles of daylight and darkness. That is actually the result of the rotation of the earth so that the sun is alternately shining on one side of the Earth or the other. Since this rotation is continuous and neither accelerates nor decelerates, at this point one cycle of day and night becomes one day consisting of twenty four hours. It is unclear if the periods of morning and evening referred to as the first three days was a literal twenty four hour cycle or not, but it would appear that God, who is invariably consistent, by declaring the first three cycles of morning and evening as days one through three would be consistent with other time periods referred to as the remaining four days, since the rotation of the Earth apparently began in;

> Genesis 1:1 KJV In the beginning God created the heaven and the earth.

Although we are not told that the Earth began its rotation at this point nor are we told that the Earth began its orbit around the non existent sun in verse 1 it is only reasonable to believe that The Earth did in fact begin to rotate on its axis and begin an orbit around a non existent Sun, since that is the primary basis for time and there were three periods referred to as days.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Bye. When the author wrote "God divided the light from the darkness", I wonder did he himself understand it or he just write it without understand it. If he understand it, did he describe it to other people on how is that "dividing light from darkness" ? :). I wonder when the author wrote "let there be light", did the author know that the other half of the earth is not in the same condition with where he live ? That's why my question is addressed to the literalist/YEC.

Comment: The author of Genesis was Moses. Moses was not present at creation, nor was he there to witness creation of light. Moses supposedly wrote the 4 books of the Pentateuch at the revelation of God himself while on the Mountain. Surely God knew, but since there was no Sun it is impossible to know whether the whole Earth or a portion was in the light, or in the darkness and it would be of no consequence since there would be no one to bask either in light or darkness. Man was not created until later.

Comment: If I'm a literalist, I wonder how Moses get the revelation. My mind ask "is it a vision or just a spoken words ?" :)

Comment: As Christians; who believe the Bible to be true, believe that Moses was told by God himself all that is covered in the first four books of the Bible. Moses stated that in Genesis, and we have no way of either proving or disproving that claim. Sometimes there is no literal answer.